# Angular - is there a way to check for the unique property of an event binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to build functionality where when I click a header, the styling on an icon changes and additional HTML is shown. I have working code as follows:

**Component**

```
export class ServicesComponent {
    interpretingTurned: Boolean = false;
    communityDevelopmentTurned: Boolean = false;
    instructingTurned: Boolean = false;

    checkIfTurned(turned) {
        if (!turned) {
            turned = true;
            this.interpretingTurned = turned; 
        } else {
            turned = false;
            this.interpretingTurned = turned;
        }
}
```

**Template (HTML)**

```
<div class="optional" fxLayout="row">
    <h6 class="optional-header" #interpretingHeader (click)="checkIfTurned(interpretingTurned)">Optional services</h6>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right" *ngIf="!interpretingTurned"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down" *ngIf="interpretingTurned"></i>
</div>
<div class="optional-section " *ngIf="interpretingTurned">
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit </li>
        <li>Sit vero recusandae minus quidem laudantium assumenda? Nostrum, error debitis</li>
        <li>Assumenda aliquid maxime dolorum quisquam sed? Officiis autem nisi soluta consectetur itaque?</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I expect to have this functionality in multiple places in the same component and was wondering how I would be able to only call checkIfTurned() so that I don't have to repeat the function wherever else I use it (e.g. Community Development, Instructing). Right now, I am only checking if the *interpreting* header is clicked.

I was thinking that there may be some unique property that I could check for and pass to checkIfTurned() but am not sure how exactly to go about this.

**What I envision**

```
export class ServicesComponent {
    interpretingTurned: Boolean = false;
    communityDevelopmentTurned: Boolean = false;
    instructingTurned: Boolean = false;

    checkIfTurned(turned) {
        if(some unique property related to event indicating it's from the Interpeting Header){ 
            if (!turned) {
                turned = true;
                this.interpretingTurned = turned; 
            } else {
                turned = false;
                this.interpretingTurned = turned;
            }
        }
        if(some unique property related to event indicating it's from the Community Development Header){ 
            if (!turned) {
                turned = true;
                this.communityDevelopmentTurned = turned; 
            } else {
                turned = false;
                this.communityDevelopmentTurned = turned;
            }
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you need the same functionality in multiple components you should make use of a `service` and inject that service into those components which need that functionality

Comment: @messerbill I'm aware of services but not sure if it's applicable in this case as it's not going to be needed outside this component. I suppose my question may not be clear enough. I'm trying to reuse functionality in several places that are all part of the same component (in this case, I have multiple cards on my page and there's something like a read more section for each card that expands when clicked)

Comment: Would making an object where each property is a different type of turn with the value of true or false work? It would allow you to do obj[turnType] to get/set the value.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution where I added an id attribute to the header and passed $event in my event binding. Used srcElement.id of $event to do a check. Looks something like:

**Template (HTML)**

```
div class="optional" fxLayout="row">
    <h6 class="optional-header" id="optional-header-interpreting" #interpretingHeader (click)="checkIfTurned(interpretingTurned, $event)">Optional services</h6>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right" id="optional-header-interpreting" (click)="checkIfTurned(interpretingTurned, $event)" *ngIf="!interpretingTurned"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down" id="optional-header-interpreting" (click)="checkIfTurned(interpretingTurned, $event)" *ngIf="interpretingTurned"></i>
</div>
...
```

**Component**

```
 checkIfTurned(turned, event) {
        if (event.srcElement.id === "optional-header-interpreting"){
        ...
        } 
        if (event.srcElement.id === "optional-header-comm-dev"){
        ...
        }
```

Comment: you already have the context of which element has been clicked, why do you need $event after all?

Comment: @ABOS Thanks for your comment. How would you propose I provide the context of the clicked element to the checkIfTurned method()?